# Code gen error or my misunderstanding?

Tags: f#

I'm seeing behavior I can't explain from the F# compiler (Visual F# 3.1.1.0)--what appears on the surface to be only the difference between having a named local and passing a temporary actually produces a behavior difference.

Am I not understanding something about F# behavior, or is this a code gen error? *(I know, the latter is more likely.)*

**Repro** - I found it difficult to repro without using Reactive Extensions, so this is about as simple as I got it. Note that `try1` and `try2` are nearly identical.

```
open System
open System.Reactive.Linq
open System.Threading

let interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5)
let testDuration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2.0)

let mkHandler () = // creates a function that closes over state
    let count  = ref 0
    fun _ -> count := !count + 1
             printfn "State is now %d" !count

let try1 () =
    printfn "try1"
    let handler = mkHandler ()
    use subscription = Observable.Interval(interval).Subscribe(handler)
    Thread.Sleep(testDuration)

let try2 () =
    printfn "try2"
    // creates handler inline:
    use subscription = Observable.Interval(interval).Subscribe(mkHandler ())
    Thread.Sleep(testDuration)

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    try1 ()
    try2 ()
    0
```

**Output** - The `try1` and `try2` functions illustrate the desired and undesirable behaviors, respectively. Output from the program is:

```
try1
State is now 1
State is now 2
State is now 3
try2
State is now 1
State is now 1
State is now 1
```

According to my understanding `try2` should behave the same as `try1`. If not, please explain how this minor difference should function differently.

---

From examining the output of a decompiler I have determined the following:

`mkHandler` is functioning correctly; it creates a function that closes over unique state. When called multiple times it mutates that state.

The same overload of `Subscribe` is called by both `try1` and `try2`: `public static IDisposable Subscribe<T>(this IObservable<T> source, Action<T> onNext)`

The behind-the-scenes helper code generated for `try1` closes over the handler function and invokes it correctly:

```
[CompilationMapping(SourceConstructFlags.Closure)]  
[Serializable]  
// subscription@16  
internal sealed class subscriptionu004016
{
    public FSharpFunc<long, Unit> handler;

    public subscriptionu004016(FSharpFunc<long, Unit> handler)
    {
    }

    internal void Invoke(long obj)
    {
        this.handler.Invoke(obj);
    }
}
```

The behind-the-scenes helper code for `try2` does not close over the handler function but calls the `mkHandler` factory function every time it's invoked; this explains the output, but is not the desired behavior:

```
[CompilationMapping(SourceConstructFlags.Closure)]
[Serializable]
// subscription@22-1
internal sealed class subscriptionu004022u002d1
{
    public subscriptionu004022u002d1()
    {
    }

    internal void Invoke(long obj)
    {
        Program.mkHandler<long>().Invoke(obj);
    }
}
```

---

To reiterate my question: Why do these two function behave differently? Is this a code gen error? None of the above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I can see, there is nothing wrong with your code - what you're doing makes sense. This seems to be a subtle bug in the F# compiler.

I suspect that there is something wrong with how the compiler resolves the `Subscribe` method. Your code is creating an F# function value, but the compiler wraps it into `Action<int64>` delegate automatically and uses Rx version of `Subscribe`. However, it does not normally automatically turn partially applied functions to delegates - it seems to be happening only in this case.

The easiest workaround seems to be to change your `mkHandler` function to explicitly create the delegate and then everything works as expected:

```
let mkHandler () = // creates a function that closes over state
    let count  = ref 0
    Action<int64>(fun _ -> 
      count := !count + 1
      printfn "State is now %d" !count)
```

**EDIT:** After some more investigation, I'd say that this is a bug which happens specifically with the `Subscribe` method of `IObservable<T>`. Since F# treats events automatically as `IObservable<T>` values, it has some special handling for them and it adds `Subscribe` method. If there is a `Subscribe` extension declared elsewhere, it clashes and things break.

The easiest repro I could find is to create a C# project with:

```
public static class Extensions {
  public static void Subscribe(this IObservable<int> c1, Action<int> f) { 
    f(1);
    f(2);
  }
}
```

And then do exactly what you did:

```
let partial() = 
  printfn "called"
  fun n -> ()

let a = new Event<int>()
let o = a.Publish.Subscribe(partial())
```

This prints "called" twice, while it should really be called just once. I created a [bug for this issue on the F# bug tracker](https://visualfsharp.codeplex.com/workitem/123).

Comment: I have another repro using only F# without RX or Observables: http://pastebin.com/QAjRJDTb

Comment: Hmm, so it really seems to be problem with conversion to the `Action` delegate. Can you add this example to the CodePlex issue? (https://visualfsharp.codeplex.com/workitem/123)