# Translating a piece of asynchronous C# code to F# (with Reactive Extensions and FSharpx)

Tags: f#, system.reactive, c#-to-f#

After a while again I was leafing through some Rx code here in SO and came across to a question [How to implement polling using Observables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19547880/how-to-implement-polling-using-observables).

Intriquing *from the F# perspective* is the use of (self-defined) `Either` type, or [Choice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353439.aspx) in F# parlor. Alas, I get the translation wrong on many levels, beginning already from the types.

But rather than just quit attempting to translate, perhaps this could be of use as a broader education tool. **Could someone lend a functioning F# brain and help translate the following piece(s) of C# code?**

I have used F# `TaskBuilder`, but noticed just recently that it doesn't implemented the [TryWith part of a computation builder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233182.aspx) in [TaskBuilder](https://github.com/fsprojects/fsharpx/blob/master/src/FSharpx.Core/ComputationExpressions/Monad.fs#L905). So, it may become difficult to translate the first piece of C# code (or perhaps one should go the `async` route), there's another version provided in the source SO link that doesn't use an asynchornous structure. Luck regarding this question, or unluck, I'm not able to translate that either.

The erros I get are of the sort:

`Type mismatch. Expecting a IScheduler -> CancellationToken -> Task but given a 'a * CancellationToken -> 'b The type 'IScheduler' does not match the type ''a * CancellationToken'`

`Type mismatch. Expecting a IObservable<Choice<'TResult,exn>> but given a
    IObservable<'TResult> The resulting type would be infinite when unifying ''TResult' and 'Choice<'TResult,exn>'`

and so forth.

- Install-Package FSharpx
- Install-Package Rx-Main

-

```
    [<Extension>]
    type ObservableExtensions() = 
        static member inline poll<'TResult, 'TArg>(asyncFunction: 'TArg -> IObservable<'TResult>, parameterFactory: 'TArg, interval:TimeSpan, scheduler: IScheduler): IObservable<Choice<'TResult, exn>> =

            Observable.Create<'TResult>(fun(observer:IObserver<'TResult>) ->
                let task = new TaskBuilder()                                     
                let t(ctrl:IScheduler, ct:CancellationToken) = task {
                    while not <| ct.IsCancellationRequested do
                        try
                            let! result = asyncFunction(parameterFactory)
                            observer.OnNext(Choice1Of2(result))
                        with ex ->
                            observer.OnNext(Choice2Of2(ex))
                        do! ctrl.Sleep(interval, ct)
                }

                scheduler.ScheduleAsync(Func<IScheduler, CancellationToken, Task>(t)))
```

And the corresponding C# code (1):

```cs
public IObservable<Either<Exception, TResult>> Poll<TResult, TArg>(
Func<TArg, IObservable<TResult>> asyncFunction,
Func<TArg> parameterFactory,
TimeSpan interval,
IScheduler scheduler)
{
return Observable.Create<Either<Exception, TResult>>(observer =>
{
    return scheduler.ScheduleAsync(async (ctrl, ct) => {
        while(!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            try
            {
                var result = await asyncFunction(parameterFactory());
                observer.OnNext(Either.Right<Exception,TResult>(result));
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                observer.OnNext(Either.Left<Exception, TResult>(ex));
            }
            await ctrl.Sleep(interval, ct);
        }
    });        
});    
}
```

Alternative C# code

```cs
public IObservable<Either<Exception, TResult>> Poll2<TResult, TArg>(
    Func<TArg, IObservable<TResult>> asyncFunction,
    Func<TArg> parameterFactory,
    TimeSpan interval,
    IScheduler scheduler)
{
    return Observable.Create<Either<Exception, TResult>>(
        observer =>
            Observable.Defer(() => asyncFunction(parameterFactory()))
                      .Select(Either.Right<Exception, TResult>)
                      .Catch<Either<Exception, TResult>, Exception>(
                        ex => Observable.Return(Either.Left<Exception, TResult>(ex)))
                      .Concat(Observable.Defer(
                        () => Observable.Empty<Either<Exception, TResult>>()
                                        .Delay(interval, scheduler)))
                      .Repeat().Subscribe(observer));
}
```

Just a note that this bears some similarity to [How to write a generic, recursive extension method in F#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23404185/how-to-write-a-generic-recursive-extension-method-in-f) and consequently to [Write an Rx “RetryAfter” extension method extension method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18978523/write-an-rx-retryafter-extension-method)

**<edit:** To complement theexcellent answer of [MisterMetaphor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/498176/mistermetaphor), I'll add a version without interval here too.

```cs
type Observable with
    static member Poll2(f: unit -> IObservable<_>, interval: TimeSpan, sched: IScheduler) : IObservable<_> =
        Observable.Create<_>(fun observer ->
            Observable.Defer(f)
                .Select(Choice1Of2)
                .Catch(Choice2Of2 >> Observable.Return)
                .Concat(Observable.Defer(fun _ -> Observable.Empty().Delay(interval, sched)))
                .Repeat()
                .Subscribe(observer))

    static member Poll2(f: 'a -> IObservable<_>, argFactory: unit -> 'a, interval: TimeSpan, sched: IScheduler) =
        Observable.Poll2(argFactory >> f, interval, sched)
```

I'm not sure if this is needed, but a due note on a subtle bug on `.Subscribe`in F# (at least of Visual F# 3.1.1.0) as discovered in SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25189077/code-gen-error-or-my-misunderstanding), more [here](https://visualfsharp.codeplex.com/workitem/123)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't absolutely have to use `Observable.Create`, you can achieve similar results with `Observable.Interval`:

```
type Observable with
    static member Poll(f : unit -> IObservable<_>, interval : TimeSpan, sched : IScheduler) : IObservable<_> =
        Observable.Interval(interval, sched)
            .SelectMany(fun _ ->
                Observable.Defer(f)
                    .Select(Choice1Of2)
                    .Catch(Choice2Of2 >> Observable.Return))

    // An overload that matches your original function
    static member Poll(f : 'a -> IObservable<_>, argFactory : unit -> 'a, interval : TimeSpan, sched : IScheduler) =
        Observable.Poll(argFactory >> f, interval, sched)
```

What I like about this implementation is that you don't have to go down to the level of directly using schedulers and `Observable.Create`. I think you should always use existing combinators/operators unless you absolutely have to do otherwise.

Also, `Observable.Interval` uses `SchedulePeriodic` (evident [here](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET/blob/master/Rx.NET/Source/System.Reactive.Linq/Reactive/Linq/Observable/Timer.cs)) which is probably more efficient and correct than your `Task`-based implementation.

Comment: I wonder if you refer to the explanation at [line 137](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET/blob/master/Rx.NET/Source/System.Reactive.Linq/Reactive/Linq/Observable/Timer.cs#L137) in the link, but that's an interesting read. No, there isn't a need to use ``Observable.Create``, at least I haven't thought about a reason. My initial idea was to just ponder this piece of code and the trouble of translating it, but this looks like even better! Cheers!

Comment: Hey, cheers. I was actually referring to the usage of `SchedulerPeriodic` at all, as it will use an OS timer internally which probably is a lot more efficient than doing `await Task.Sleep(...)`s. But yeah, there are also a lot of intricacies there , which is even better reason to use `Observable.Interval`.

Comment: Heh, I see you asked from James about not using ``Interval``. Just a note here for anyone reading that there was a reason. James' answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19547880/how-to-implement-polling-using-observables), see the comments.